# Bundle-wide configuration variables in Symfony 2 and TWIG

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm programming in Symfony 2, where I have two bundles to maintain. Their views extend the base.html.twig (app-wide template) like:

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}
...
```

Now the base.html.twig looks like:

```
...
<title>{{ page_title }}</title>
...
```

Now my question is how and where I can define the variable page_titel in order that the two bundles have different page-titles. I know, I could set the variable within the template-rendering in each action-method of the controller, but due the fact that the page-titel is static within one bundle, I'm searching an approach where I only have to define the variable once. Something like:

```
#app/config/config.yml
twig:
  global:
    foo: bar
```

but not application-wide, but bundle-wide!
Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering reading up on TWIG blocks.
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html

In your base template use:

```
<title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
```

Then in your app templates use:

```
{% block title %}Bundle 1 Title{% endblock %}
```

And the title will magically show up as the title content.

And I'm not 100% sure I understood your question.  But you can give each bundle it's own base.html that extends the master base.html and sets the title.  Everything in that bundle would then extend the bundle base.  So the title would only need to be set in one spot.